# install SQL Profiler for SQL Server Express

Tags: windows, installation, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am not sure what I did while installing SQL server express 2008 but sql profiler is not on my machine. is there a way to get that separately? my machine is not running on a server OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Microsoft SQL Server profiler is only available with commercial versions of SQL Server. However, there are third party tools for helping to profile a SQL Server Express instance:

- [SQL Server 2005/2008 Express Profiler](https://sites.google.com/site/sqlprofiler/)
- [SQL Express Profiler](http://code.google.com/p/sqlexpressprofiler/)

Comment: The links are no longer active, do you maybe still have a working link?